# Storing result of switch case in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a switch case as follows:

```
def result
  case params[:q]
  when "r4c_001"
    result = "r4c"
    description = "001"
  end
end
```

When I am dealing with single value inside `when`, then I can also implement it as:

```
def result
  result = case params[:q]
  when "r4c_001"
    "r4c"
  end
end
```

How can I do it for multiple values, like:

```
def result
  result, description = case params[:q]
  when "r4c_001"
    result = "r4c"
    description = "001"
  end
end
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: its supposed to mean i am having hard time getting adapted to ruby's syntax from java. Yes i have corrected it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def result
  case params[:q]
  when "r4c_001"
    ["r4c", "001"]
  end
end
```

And use it as:

```
result, description = result()
```

---

*Sidenote:* in this particular case the same goal might be achieved even easier:

```
def result
  params[:q].split('_') if params[:q] == "r4c_001"
end
```

*Sidenote2:* unless `params` is a method of the same class, returning an instance of the object, responding to `#[]`, you should pass `params` to the method explicitly:

```
def result(params)
  case params[:q]
  when "r4c_001"
    ["r4c", "001"]
  end
end
```

And use it as:

```
result, description = result(params)
```

Comment: thanks for the side note but my intention is different. For the simplicity i have framed my question like this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to return two values from the `result` method.  You can do that in a return statement.

```
def result
 case params[:q]
 when "r4c_001"
  return "r4c", "001"
 end
end

result, description = result()
```

I just saw mudasobwa's answer and his sidenote is an excellent point and could save you a long case statement.

Comment: Assignment inside of `result` does nothing.

Comment: Also, while this does work, I personally would consider this bad ruby (adding force returns in the middle of an expression). But maybe that's just me :)

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Thanks for helping me. I like using [..] instead of the return keyword

Comment: You can also do return with array, that would work identically.  @SergioTulentsev I actually find the return clearer, as I don't have to worry about whether someone's added additional code after the case end.  But that's just me :)

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: fair enough :) But would you agree that for such "imperative" branching, if/elsif would be better?